# Am I a programmer or a developer?

Tags: work-environment, title

Are the term *programmer* and *developer* interchangeable?

Is it that *programmer* is more an old usage, and *developer* is more trending, or there is more to it?

I can understand a *coder* is someone that may only *code* according to low-level designs, but *programmer* can start their project from high-level designs, or even user-requirement analysis, right?

*"Sites that aren't language-related don't appreciate questions on semantics when the answers can't provide more meaningful information than a dictionary could"*

If the answer exists in a dictionary, why would I ask it here? As Brandin has put it,

> "Programmer" is the "everyman's" job title... OTOH when you say "developer", the everyman will probably think you're talking about something else, unrelated to computers.

E.g., *programmer* is a much better word than *developer*, but nowadays everyone tends to use *developer* and avoid *programmer*. It doesn’t make sense to me to go for a poorer choice, so I want to know *why*. No dictionary can explain why people are doing that. Furthermore, most people are doing that even without knowing why they are doing it. I understand that most of them don’t care, but I want to know.

My theory is because of the UI developers (who are not exactly programmers), and want to verify how well accepted that theory is (apparently not).

Comment: I've always seen them as interchangeable, but I always use _developer_ personally

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Workplace is not a dictionary.

Comment: @Lilienthal, understandable. But we both agree that this is workplace related, right? You many not care about the answer, but I do care. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: [Don't call yourself a programmer](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2011/10/28/dont-call-yourself-a-programmer/).

Comment: Counter-argument to nvoigt's blog post is here: http://simpleprogrammer.com/2013/05/26/job-titles/
All being said, "Programmer" is the "everyman's" job title. Like "teacher", "janitor", "manager", etc. Everyone knows what you mean when you say those words, even though your official job title may be different. OTOH when you say "developer", the everyman will probably think you're talking about something else, unrelated to computers.

Comment: @grn No, I don't agree. It's equally (ir)relevant on StackOverflow or the Programmers SE and doesn't belong on any of those sites because it's purely a language question. Sites that aren't language-related don't appreciate questions on semantics when the answers can't provide more meaningful information than a dictionary could.

Comment: Traditional photographic pun: I'm not just a developer, I'm also a fixer.

Comment: Does it really matter, does your friend or your mom really care or know what the difference is between programmer and developer? Will it help on a resume? I think any quality employer will be more concerned with what you have experience in and accomplished in your previous jobs than the difference between programmer and developer.

Comment: *"Most of them don’t care, but I want to know"*, I just updated my OP explaining why I asked. To all those who want to close it, apparently you don’t care. It never bothers you, but it bothers me. Your using political reasons to shut me up is the same as saying, “I don’t care, so you shouldn’t either”.

Comment: Rather than on hold, it should be closed because the *Job Title* is defined by the company you are working for.  It is a matter of company policy to decide if they use Programmer or Developer.  There is no universal standard title for one that writes code.

Comment: @NotMe, I'm affraid you've missed the whole point. My question has nothing to do what Job Title my company gives me. It is "developer" BTW. I'm not asking for the universal standard, please read my question again to see what exactly I'm asking.

Comment: While not precisely the same as each can be used in other contexts: Programs could be recreational activities rather than software, development could be personal or professional that similarly could exist outside of IT. Context matters but I doubt that point would be understood properly.

Comment: I believe "programmer" fell out of favor after the dotcom bust, where people wanted to distinguish themselves from read-a-book-can-write-html "programmers" and started calling themselves software developers/engineers.  I.e., anyone can program, but writing maintainable, extensible software is a whole other thing.

Comment: Thanks @adeady, that's exactly the behind-the-scene reasons that I want to dig out.

Answer (score 8):

Everywhere I have worked, the two terms have been interchangeable. Programmer as you said was used earlier, but developer has no difference that I can think of. I think it also depends where you are on which is used. No one calls them developers over here, but in NZ I heard them called both.

Comment: To add a little to this response - I find when you consider web developers, you don't see the term "web programmer". I'v always considered developer to be more for "overall" areas (such as web development, server development, etc), where as programmer was a more general use (e.g. He is a Java Programmer). Note that it could still go both ways (e.g. He is a Java Developer infers a wider knowledge in Java). I expect like you mentioned its probably also very cultural dependent.

Answer (score 4):

A title means exactly what a particular company intends it to mean nothing more nothing less.

Some companies use "programmer".  Some companies use "developer".  Some use both.  Some use neither.  A company that uses both may have some sort of hierarchy.  Or it may not.  A "Developer 1" at one company could well be the most senior title for someone that writes code while at another company "Developer 1" is the most junior title.  I wouldn't get too hung up on a title.

If someone is looking at a resume, the description of what someone did is far more important than the title.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  A programmer is a software developer.   A higher level person would be like senior developer, design lead, or architect.  The term senior (or junior)
 programmer is just not (typically) used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no...

They tend to be on a spectrum - with developers expected to have more independence in direction than a programmer, but there's a rather large overlap.

Like any other role, it isn't the title as much as the job description (and responsibilities) which you need to look at.